# DOM nodes creation vs perfomance

Tags: javascript

I have a function that dynamically creates DOM nodes to accomodate GPS JSON data from a server. As number of nodes increases, browser performance also
degrades. Is there any means to rewrite/tweak the function to improve performance? The simplified node creation part of the function works as shown below:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
table.appendChild(tbody);
for(var i = 0; i<3000;i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<50;j++){
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.style.backgroundColor="#a"+j%10+'c';
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: If you have a table with thousands of rows, there is probably something wrong with your design.

Comment: A table with 150000 cells? That's insane. What do you actually need?

Comment: I have just used those numbers to test browser performance so as to look for a simpler and inexpensive way of creating nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using some kind of **Recyclable List**.

Such lists recycle their elements by deleting DOM nodes that lie outside the viewport and recreating them when currently viewed.

Long story short - only currently-viewed DOM nodes exist in the DOM at any given time

Another technique is to use a fixed number of cells which you then fill with data according to where the user is scrolled

AFAIK there's no other way to go about this - naively creating 150,000 DOM nodes would completely decimate your scrolling performance

#### Some Examples

- [An example](http://elliottsprehn.com/personal/infinite-scroll.html) in pure JS
- [An example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/iron-list/demo/basic.html) that's build on top of [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)
- [Another example](https://github.com/gnoff/react-everscroll) build on top of [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)

Here's how the pure JS example handles this:

*Source: http://elliottsprehn.com/personal/infinite-scroll.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    ul, li { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; }

    #infinite-list {
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 1em;
        position: relative;
    }

    #infinite-list .scroll-view {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: -webkit-calc(20em + 2px);
    }

    #infinite-list ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 16px);
    }

    #infinite-list li { 
        height: 2em;
        line-height: 2em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #infinite-list li:last-child { 
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    #infinite-list .scroll-view .spacer {
        height: -webkit-calc(2em * 20000);
    }
</style>

<h1>Infinite Scrolling with a fixed number of DOM nodes</h1>

<div id="infinite-list">
    <div class="scroll-view">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    function randRange(low, high) {
         return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low)) + low;
    }

    function randPick(array) {
        return array[randRange(0, array.length)];
    }

    // Randomly create a bunch of test data.
    var tlds = ['.com', '.net', '.org', '.edu', '.co.uk'];
    var domains = ['google', 'facebook', 'yahoo', 'apple', 'youtube', 'amazon'];
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) {
        data.push(i + ' ' + randPick(domains) + randPick(tlds));
    }

    var list = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#infinite-list li');
    var scrollView = document.querySelector('#infinite-list .scroll-view');

    var itemHeight = listItems[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    var previous;

    // Propagate scrolling with the mouse wheel.
    list.onmousewheel = function(e) {
        var delta = e.wheelDeltaY;
        if (Math.abs(delta) < itemHeight) {
            delta = itemHeight * (delta > 0 ? 1 : -1);
        }
        scrollView.scrollTop -= delta;
    };

    function update() {
        var current = scrollView.scrollTop;
        if (previous == current) {
            webkitRequestAnimationFrame(update);
            return;
        }
        previous = current;
        var first = Math.ceil(current / itemHeight);
        for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; ++i) {
            listItems[i].firstElementChild.textContent = data[first++];
        }
        webkitRequestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    update();

})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already, you might want to hide the element you are creating nodes in, and only show it at the end of your loop.

E.g. set `display:none;` on it while you are working on it, and then switch back to `display:block;` (or whichever it is) afterwards.

Update: Actually, you don't even need to hide it, though that's one way to do it. The cleaner way is to wait with adding your table to the document until you finish adding all nodes to it, and then only add it to the body afterwards.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
for(var i = 0; i<3000;i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<50;j++){
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = "#a"+j%10+'c';
        td.style.backgroundColor="#a"+j%10+'c';
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Scrolling performance would be completely decimated in any case - he's creating 150,000 DOM nodes

Comment: @nicholas Possibly, but the question was about improving performance of the function. I suspect the browser is having a field day with redrawing (or at least, it might have in the past, since I'm basing this on past experience). That said, your solution is definitely the best one in terms of overall  performance.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides It seems my browser is quite happy to scroll through 150,000 nodes. 1,500,000 nodes too (though generation takes ages). But I suspect that's mainly due to them being the only things in the page, so it can do something like you described at a lower level.

Comment: That's probably because you're not triggerring any [layout thrashing](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) and/or [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow), due to the simplicity of your page - as soon as you do it will get laggy - I'm amazed nonetheless

Comment: @Aeolun, You are right! I am looking for a solution for handling node creation, because that's where performance is degraded

Comment: @AlbertSenghor If you are looking for a way to do the node creation quickly, that'd be NicholasKyriakides answer, as that concept will only be creating a few hundred nodes at a time, and change the data in them from JSON source (which is much, much faster). If you only have the 150k nodes, doing it the way in my post takes about 4s to create/add all nodes, which may or may not be too much (and as Nicholas pointed out, will probably have wrecked performance if you do anything but draw the nodes).

Answer (score 0):

It might help to enlist the browser's help by making a template for a single row, then cloning it repeatedly:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
table.appendChild(tbody);
// Make a template row once up front
var rowtemplate = document.createElement('tr');
for(var j=0;j<50;j++){
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.style.backgroundColor="#a"+j%10+'c';
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
// Now clone it over and over instead of creating it piecemeal repeatedly
// Must pass true to ensure it clones whole tree, not just top level tr
for(var i = 0; i<3000;i++){
    table.appendChild(rowtemplate.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Obviously, it depends on the browser internals whether this helps, but typically, the browser should be able to clone an existing node tree faster than manually creating each element from scratch.